# How to enable framebuffer transparency in GLFW?

Tags: c, opengl, transparency, glfw

I am stuck with window transparency in GLFW, I followed their window guide and examples but nothing seems to work...
GLFW version 3.3 with OpenGL 3.3 as well.

I went through the gears example in GLFW's repository, which introduces a completely transparent window, copied the required window hint (`GLFW_FRAMEBUFFER_TRANSPARENCY`) and set it to true. This does not work for me

I am initializing my window using the following:

```c
if (!glfwInit()) {
    printf("Could not initialize GLFW\n");
    return 1;
}

GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "opengl", NULL, NULL);
if (!window) {
    printf("Could not create GLFW window");
    return 1;
}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, 1);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER, 1);

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
glfwSwapInterval(1);
glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, resizeCallback);
```

Then I clear this way:

```c
glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I expect the window to be semi-transparent, did I missed something?

Comment: As far as the code in the question goes, you will have a cleared back buffer. So even if your system / compositor supports this kind of transparency, there is no reason for it to appear at this point.

Comment: @derhass: Since I don't understand what is happening: Could you explain why an alpha of 0.1 shouldn't cause a transparent window?

Comment: The code is far from being a complete example. I just tried to point out that it is unclear if that buffer content is ever swapped to the front buffer.

Comment: @derhass: I copied his code in an otherwise perfectly working example. When all of the color channels are 1, then the window is not transparent, no matter what alpha is. E.g. (1,1,1,0) is completely opaque. (1,0,1,0) is partially transparent. I can't explain what is happening though.

Comment: @BDL that looks like your compositor is expecting pre-multiplied alpha.

Answer (score 1):

`glfwWindowHint` has to be called **before** the window gets created (which can be seen in the demo you mentioned). Otherwise they do not have any effect. Correct code:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, 1);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER, 1);

GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "opengl", NULL, NULL);
if (!window) {
    printf("Could not create GLFW window");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This gives the same result

Comment: @AregevDev What I wrote is definitely a problem. But there seems to be some other issues with the clear color. When I set it to (0,0,0,0), the window gets transparent. At the moment where I set all channels to one (1,1,1,0) transparency is gone. Unfortunately, I really can't explain why this happens.